# Signed and unsigned registers

Tags: adc, register

What is it mean when the digital code of the output of an ADC is signed? Does it have to do with application? Does it mean that the corresponding output value that is calculated is negative?

Comment: When sampling a signal that may assume positive or negative values there has to be a method for representing the sign. 2's complement arithmetic is a very convenient means of achieving this and allows mathematical operations to automatically take care of the sign bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your ADC but usually, if it's signed then it means the value it sampled is negative in reference to ground. And the output will usually be a 2's compliment of the value.